# read two bytes at once from a byte array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory

Let's say I have the following array of bytes:

```
uint8_t barr[4] = {0xCE, 0xCE, 0xCE, 0xCE};
```

Given an index `n`, I want to be able to read two bytes:

```
uint16_t d16 = barr[0];
```

And have `d16` be equal to

```
0xCECE
```

Perhaps there is a function in the standard library that can perform such task?

Comment: All of your sample values are the same. Should `0x01, 0x02` be paired as `0x0102` or as `0x0201`? Do you know the endianness of the data *and* of your own system?

Answer (score 9):

A piece of cake:

```
memcpy(&d16, barr + n, sizeof(d16));
```

---

Don't try to convert pointers or use `union`s. Those either are undefined behaviors, or may trip trap representations. `memcpy()` is the "canonical" solution (as the C++ boost library does).

Comment: All wise, a simple and sufficient answer.

Comment: @JanParzydło Not so easy, propably You should read about endianess.  Think sample with different values { 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14 }

Comment: Why is boost a reference when doing C?

Comment: @alk This is the same case across C and C++.

Comment: You never know ... ;-)

Comment: @alk Fine. [I have to agree.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203/5958455)

Answer (score 0):

A linear and endianness-safe approach here:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> /* for ntohs() */

union Convert
{
  uint16_t  to_integer_big_endian;
  uint8_t barr[sizeof (uint16_t)];
};

uint16_t pick_and_convert(uint8_t * barr, size_t s, size_t n)
{
  union Convert c = {0};  /* Take out-of-bound bytes as 0s. */

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof c.barr && (n + i) < s; ++i)
  {
    c.barr[i] = barr[n + i];
  }

  return ntohs(c.to_integer_big_endian);
}

int main(void)
{
   uint8_t barr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; /* Assuming a binary sequence. */
   size_t n;

   scanf("%zu", &n);

   uint16_t to_integer = pick_and_convert(barr, sizeof barr / sizeof *barr, n);

   printf("result = 0x%hx\n", to_integer);
 }
```